# How to get selective columns and then rows from a a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using a pandas dataframe and I wanted to put filter on certain columns and then extract only those rows that satisfy a given constraint.

So below is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C' : np.random.randn(8),
                   'D' : np.random.randn(8)})

df

     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -0.575010 -0.271119
1  bar    one -0.130209 -0.106217
2  foo    two  0.093987 -1.351369
3  bar  three -0.403304  0.983619
4  foo    two  0.668989  0.249099
5  bar    two  1.153876  1.407159
6  foo    one  1.453793 -0.347721
7  foo  three  0.493562 -0.051688
```

And I want to get B and D columns and then apply a filter in a loop so to get the selective columns I sliced as `for col in df.loc[:, ["B", "D"]]` that produces the following output:

```
      B             D
0    one       -0.271119
1    one       -0.106217
2    two       -1.351369
3    three      0.983619
4    two        0.249099
5    two        1.407159
6    one       -0.347721
7    three     -0.051688
```

But after this, I am nt able to get apply a selective filtering in if statement to get those rows. So the final output is get only rows from B and D that is not equal to "one" value for column 'B'

```
      B             D
2    two       -1.351369
3    three      0.983619
4    two        0.249099
5    two        1.407159
7    three     -0.051688
```

Comment: [read about indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `query` after selecting columns.

```
df[['B', 'D']].query('B != "one"')

       B         D
2    two  0.611362
3  three  0.400219
4    two -0.959443
5    two  1.494226
7  three -1.471558
```

Answer (score 3):

Basic usage of `.loc`

```
df.loc[df.B.ne('one'),['B','D']]
Out[207]: 
       B         D
2    two  0.742752
3  three -1.264271
4    two -0.112787
5    two  0.667358
7  three -0.213575
```